# Opencv installed but unable import in python

Tags: python, macos, opencv, computer-vision

Installed opencv on Macbook yosemite 10.10.2.

Ran the following commands

```
$sudo port install opencv
$export PYTHONPATH=/Users/swiftguy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

When I try to import 'opencv' in Python

```
$python
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
```

Again I cross checked whether opencv is actually installed with the following command

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv 
2.4.9 (output)
```

How do I successfully import 'opencv' in python ? Is my **export PYTHONPATH** command correct?

Please help me out.

Comment: You are most likely not using your system python, also is the cv2.so in the directory you added to the path?

Comment: Actually I don't see how adding Anaconda to your PYTHONPATH is going to help, does port install for the system python or where exactly?

Comment: Im confused where my system 'python' is installed. cv2.so file is not there and not to be found in the entire filesystem.

Comment: "$ which python" command results in the following path /Users/swiftguy/anaconda/bin/python

Comment: You should be importing cv2 not cv

Comment: Tried .. still the same error

Comment: what does `which -a python` outptu?

Comment: $which -a python (enter)
/Users/swiftguy/anaconda/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: what does `locate -b cv2.so` output?

Comment: $locate ~ -b cv2.so(enter) .. result is 100s of files which are unrelated to opencv

Comment: so there is no `python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79859/discussion-between-swift-guy-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import cv2 instead of importing cv and that should do the trick, if it doesn't please cross-check if your versions of python and openCV are compatible.

Answer (score -1):

To install opencv with the python bindings using mac ports you need to specify Python in the installation. Try:

> sudo port install opencv +python27

You should be able to do

> python -c "import cv2"